# Python: convert list to comma separted values in a varibale to pass where IN condition

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm new to python. I have the list named X in python.

```
X = ['1', '2','3']
```

I wanted to convert like below. so that I can directly pass to the SQL statement where IN condition (1,2,3).

```
xVals= 1,2,3

sql = '''SELECT  * from [dbo].[customer] where c_id in (%s)''' % (xVals)
```

What are the possible ways to do it?

Comment: So you want to create a tuple instead of a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to `f-strings` in a recent version of python?

```py
X = ['1', '2','3']

sql = f'''SELECT * from [dbo].[customer] where c_id in {tuple(int(x) for x in X)}''' 

print(sql)
```

Output:

```
SELECT * from [dbo].[customer] where c_id in (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks @quamrana, Yes this what I wanted. I Really appreciate your timely assistance.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea. Are you trying to ask a different question?

Comment: what I thought to ask, I had data frame.
val= rslt_df['cus_id']
X = val.to_string(index=False).split('\n')
#out X = ['1', '2','3'], is this corrcet approch dataframe to getting this (1,2,3) output

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Keep in mind I have not shortened the code further more for readability purposes.

```py
def convert_list_to_csv(lst):
    vals = ""
    for i in lst:
        "" += ","+ str(i)
    return vals[1:]

print(convert_list_to_csv([1, 2, 3]))
```

If you have any other queries regarding this question please let me know I'll be up!
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

you can use join method to convert list to string and add '( )'

```
xVar=' ('+','.join(X)+')'
```